# How to create custom Spinner?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am creating a custom `Spinner` in Xamarin.Android with text and image. I've created the  `Spinner` in Xamarin but don't know how to customise it.

For example how do I create rounded corners and with customised text and image?

Can anyone tell me how to achieve this? I was not able to upload the screen shot of what i have done so far since my reputation is low.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is done exactly the same way as in Native Android development. You need to implement a custom `Adapter` to fill the `Spinner` with `View`s that live up to your requirement. Such an `Adapter` handles which `View` is shown when and at which position. It handles inflating these `View`s and populating them with the correct data.

As for styling the `Spinner`, it is done through the Styling system that Android provides. Which is not specific to how Xamarin.Android (or MonoDroid) does it.

You need to look into the [documentation about Custom `Adapter`s](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/working_with_listviews_and_adapters/part_3_-_customizing_a_listview%27s_appearance/), read Creating Custom Row Layouts (in this case they are for `ListView`, but can easily be adapted to `Spinner` by overriding and implementing the `GetDropDownView`) and [`Spinner`](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/spinner/)